# Table exceeds the page width

Tags: tables, width

I have a large table, and I don't want it to exceed the page limit. Please see the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}    
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l 
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l }
\hline
DM    & Option   & States &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
X     & Option A & N      & Y & N & N & Y & N & N & Y & N & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  \\
      & Option B & N      & N & Y & N & N & Y & N & N & N & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  \\
Y     & Option C & N      & N & N & Y & Y & Y & N & N & N & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  & N  & N  & N  \\
      & Option D & N      & N & N & N & N & N & Y & Y & N & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  \\
Z     & Option E & Y      & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & N & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  \\
      & Option F & N      & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & Y & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  \\
      & Option G & N      & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  \\ \hline
Label &          & 1      & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I feel like there's probably a better way of getting a shaded background to your table, but still, at least as a point of interest, you might like to know that you can optimise that code with `*{28}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}l}` The `*{n}{x}` syntax means *n* copies of the column specifier. So `*{5}{l}` would mean 5 left-aligned columns. Used in specifying table columns, and possibly some other places, but not generally. Can be used multiple times, e.g. `*{2}{c}rl*{5}{p{1cm}}`

Comment: Please state the page width, the width of the text block, the document font size, and the font you use (if not Computer Modern).

Comment: This has to be a duplicate...

Answer (score 10):

The table is much too wide for a normal portrait page.

- Therefore the following example rotates it via environment `sidewaystable` of package `rotating`.
- The width of the table is still too large, therefore it is decreased by
  reducing the space between columns via setting `\tabcolsep` to a smaller value.
- The background color is set by a simple `\colorbox` instead of coloring each column individually with the same color. `\colorbox` uses an additional margin, which is controlled by `\fboxsep`, which is set to zero here locally.
- The lines are set by the macros of package `booktabs`, which have a nicer spacing behavior.
- Package `caption` fixes the vertical spacing around table caption, which appear on top of the `tabular`.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
  \begin{sidewaystable}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.73\tabcolsep}%
    \colorbox[HTML]{EFEFEF}{%
      \begin{tabular}{*{28}{l}}%
        \toprule
        DM    & Option   & \multicolumn{26}{c}{States} \\
        \midrule
        X     & Option A & N      & Y & N & N & Y & N & N & Y & N & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  \\
              & Option B & N      & N & Y & N & N & Y & N & N & N & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  \\
        Y     & Option C & N      & N & N & Y & Y & Y & N & N & N & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  & N  & N  & N  \\
              & Option D & N      & N & N & N & N & N & Y & Y & N & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  \\
        Z     & Option E & Y      & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & N & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  \\
              & Option F & N      & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & Y & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  \\
              & Option G & N      & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  \\
        \midrule
        Label &          & 1      & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}%
    }%
  \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: +1 for the use of `\colorbox` and `\fboxsep=0pt` to simplify the code that colors the entire `tabular` environment.

Comment: (+1) Maybe a `\multicolumn{3}{l}{States}`would also reduce the tablewidth, and look nicer?

Comment: @Bernard - I suspect that the word "States" should actually be centered across columns 3 thru 28. (That, at least, is the choice I made in my answer...)

Comment: @Mico Yes, fixed.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your document uses a "normal" paper size (A4 or US letter), "normal" page margin (say, 1 inch), and font size of 10pt, it is possible (though only just) to make the table fit inside the text block without rotating it into "landscape" mode. I suggest you

- reorganize the table's header by combining the header and footer lines and center the label "States" over columns 3 thru 28,
- eliminate some redundancies in the column labelled "Option".
- use a `tabular*` environment to set the width of the table equal to `\textwidth`, and

Separately, I would also like to suggest that you use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package (instead of `\hline`) and add a bit of whitespace between some of the rows. These changes will help a reader's eye glide over the copious material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page and text block parameters
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let "tabular*" figure out intercolumn widths
\colorbox[HTML]{EFEFEF}{% % see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326578/5001
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{28}{l}}
\toprule
DM    & Option   & \multicolumn{26}{c}{States}\\
\cmidrule{3-28}
      &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
\midrule
X     & A & N & Y & N & N & Y & N & N & Y & N & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  \\
      & B & N & N & Y & N & N & Y & N & N & N & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  & N  & N  & Y  \\ 
\addlinespace
Y     & C & N & N & N & Y & Y & Y & N & N & N & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  & N  & N  & N  \\
      & D & N & N & N & N & N & N & Y & Y & N & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  \\ 
\addlinespace
Z     & E & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & Y & N & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  \\
      & F & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & Y & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  \\
      & G & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & N  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  & Y  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: very nice answer and good explanation. Unortunately I can't vote twice for it :-(.  I store it into my local "bank" of very good and usable answers ...

Comment: @Zarko - Many thanks for the compliment! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Why not swap rows and columns? Here is a way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, multirow, stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
  \centering
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{my-label}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{\belowrulesep}
  \rowcolors{1}{white}{Lavender!90!lightgray}
  \setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
  \begin{tabular}{crl*{9}{c}c}
    \toprule
   \rowcolor{white} & DM: & \multicolumn{2}{c}{X}  & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Y}  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Z} \\
    \cmidrule {3-4} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{9-11}
    \rowcolor{white} Label & Options: & A & B &   & C & D &   & E & F & G \\
    \midrule
    1 & & N & N &   & N & N &   & Y & N & N \\
    2 &  & Y & N & &  N & N &  & Y & N & N \\
    3 &  & N & Y  & &  N & N &  & Y & N & N \\
    4 &  & N & N & &  Y & N &  & Y & N & N \\ 
    5 &  & Y & N & &  Y & N &  & Y & N & N \\
    6 &  & N & Y & &  Y & N &  & Y & N & N \\
    7 &  & N & N & &  N & Y &  & Y & N & N \\
    8 &  & Y & N & &  N & Y &  & Y & N & N \\
    9 &  & N & N &   & N & N &   & N & Y & N \\
  10 &  & Y & N & &  N & N &  & N & Y & N \\
  11 &  & N & Y  & &  N & N &  & N & Y & N \\
  12 &  & N & N & &  Y & N &  & N & Y  & N \\
  13 &  & Y & N & &  Y & N &  & N & Y & N \\
  14 &  & N & Y & &  Y & N &  & N & Y & N \\
  15 &  & N & N & &  N & Y &  & N & Y & N \\
  16 &  & Y & N & &  N & Y &  & N & Y & N \\
  17 &  & N & Y & &  N & Y &  & N & Y & N \\
  18 &  & N & N &   & N & N &   & N & N& Y \\
  19 &  & Y & N &   & N & N &   & N & N& Y \\
  20 &  & N & Y &   & N & N &   & N & N& Y \\
  21 &  & N & N &   & Y & N &   & N & N& Y \\
  22 &  & Y & N &   & Y & N &   & N & N& Y \\
  23 &  & N & Y &   & Y & N &   & N & N& Y \\
  24 &  & N & N &   & N & Y &   & N & N& Y \\ 
  25 &  & Y & N &   & N & Y &   & N & N& Y \\
  26 &  \multirow{-26}{*}[2ex]{\setlength\fboxrule{0.8pt}\fcolorbox{ VioletRed!80!}{white}{\scshape \Shortstack{s\\t\\a\\t\\e\\s}}} %
  & N & Y &   & N & Y &   & N & N& Y \\  
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]